# CSS disabled input in table's column backcolor and selected row in the table

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'd say in advance that CSS is my weakest point. I have an angularJs table created with the following ng-repeat statement:

```html
 <table id="lineItemsTable"
                           class="table table-bordered table-hover table-list scroll">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>@Labels.itemId</th>
                                <th>@Labels.nickname</th>
                                <th>@Labels.description</th>
                                <th class="text-right">@Labels.quantity</th>
                                <th ng-if="crud.model.adjType>=0">@Labels.location</th>
                                <th ng-if="crud.model.adjType<0">@Labels.cost</th>
                                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat-start="result in crud.model.lineItems track by $index"
                                ng-form="lineItemForm"
                                ng-click="crud.selectedMatrixIndex=-1;crud.selectedIndex=$index;"
                                ng-class="{selected: $index === crud.selectedIndex}">
```

So, the selected row in my grid (table) is highlighted with blue color using this css class:

```css
    .table-list > tbody > tr.selected td {
        background: rgba(204, 229, 255, 1);
    }
```

Also, in that same table I have the disabled cost created with the following HTML:

```html
<td>                                
                                    <input type="number" name="cost" 
                                           ng-if="crud.model.adjType<0"
                                           ng-model="result.unitCost"
                                           data-sm:number-format
                                           data-accuracy="2"
                                           data-sm:number
                                           ng-disabled="true"
                                           ng-class="{'smYellow' : (result.unitCost>0 && result.costOverride === true), 'smOrange': result.unitCost===0 }"
                                           class="form-control form-control-sm text-right">
                                </td>
```

where smYellow class is the following:

```css
.smYellow {
    fill: #faf37e;
    fill-opacity: 0.4;
    stroke: #faf37e;
    stroke-width: 3;
    background-color: rgba(250,243,126, 0.40) !important;
}
```

The problem I'm getting here is when the row is not highlighted, my yellow color looks fine. However, when the row is highlighted, I see the green (blue + yellow). I'm wondering if there is a CSS trick or some clever solution for this problem so my color looks the same when the row highlighted or not (or, at least, more yellow than green).

I'll appreciate any ideas.

UPDATE. Tried the suggested idea but still seeing green - what am I doing wrong?

```css
.smOrange {
    fill: #F58025;
    fill-opacity: 0.4;
    stroke: #F58025;
    stroke-width: 3;
    background-color: rgba(245, 128, 37, 0.40) !important;
}

.smYellow {
    fill: #faf37e;
    fill-opacity: 0.4;
    stroke: #faf37e;
    stroke-width: 3;
    background-color: rgba(250,243,126, 0.40) !important;
}

.table-list > tbody > tr.selected td > input.smYellow {
    background-color: rgba(250,243,126, 1);
    fill-opacity: 1;
}
.table-list > tbody > tr.selected td > input.smOrange {
    background-color: rgba(245, 128, 37, 1);
    fill-opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Could you give us an example of your code? from what I tried to understand from your question I made such an example code - http://plnkr.co/edit/Ty6Hewim4Wp3N8JSDSDy?p=preview

Comment: Yes, your sample shows my problem. As you can see, the highlighted row is greenish, while when row is not highlighted it's yellow. I'd like to have yellow regardless of highlight. I've been thinking of extra ng-class with the condition for selected row (may be nested ng-class) and perhaps try to use a different yellow (different opacity?) in this case. Haven't tried that idea yet as it's not too important.

Comment: The reason it's greenish is because you have set the opacity to `0.40`, so some of the blue background behind the input is bleeding through. Blue plus yellow equals green, so that's why it's green. Set the opacity to `1` instead

Comment: @Naomi like up above - change opacity 0.40 to 1 and color will not change

Comment: Right, but this is a requirement of my User Story. We want opacity 0.40. I'm thinking to add an extra class for the highlighted yellow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you see green when the row is selected is because you have the background for your input set to 40% opacity(alpha) and the blue background is bleeding through:

```
    .smYellow {
      background-color: rgba(250,243,126, 0.40);  // R,G,B,alpha
    }
```

Since blue + yellow = green, green is what you see. Set the opacity(alpha) to 100% and you should see solid yellow for the input no matter what is selected:

```
    .smYellow {
      background-color: rgba(250,243,126, 1);    // R,G,B,alpha
    }
```

Or, you can make another, more specific rule that will let you set a different color when the row is selected:

```
    .table-list > tbody > tr.selected td > input.smYellow{
      background-color: rgba(250,243,126, 0.4); // put your new matching color here
    }
```

This will require you to remove the `!important` statement from your `smYellow` rule.

Comment: I like your last suggestion and going to try it. I was thinking (and started to research) on applying multiple ng-class based on some complex nested conditions, but if I can do what you suggested with css it sounds much better and easier - thanks a lot. BTW, I only now saw your answer.

Comment: I tried your solution, but it's not working for me. I'm adding details into the post - may be you'll see what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remove the `!important` statement from your `smOrange` and `smYellow` rules. Those tell the browser to override your other rules. You don't want that in this case, you want cascading to happen

Comment: Funny, I was thinking about it too, going to try it now, thanks.

Comment: :) Now the original yellow doesn't look like a yellow when record is not highlighted and orange looks like a yellow :)

Answer (score 0):

This is my final solution which seems to work well. I'm keeping it as is.

Thanks again for your help:

```css
.smOrange {
    fill: #F58025;
    fill-opacity: 0.4;
    stroke: #F58025;
    stroke-width: 3;
    background-color: rgba(245, 128, 37, 0.40) !important;    
}

.smYellow {
    fill: #faf37e;
    fill-opacity: 0.4;
    stroke: #faf37e;
    stroke-width: 3;
    background-color: rgba(250,243,126, 0.40) !important;
}

.table-list > tbody > tr.selected td > input.smYellow {
    background-color: rgba(250,243,126, 0.60) !important;
}

.table-list > tbody > tr.selected td > input.smOrange {
    background-color: rgba(245, 128, 37, 0.60) !important;
}
```